# XSLT: How to dynamically loop through and call the templates and display items?

Tags: xslt, loops

I have an XML like this

```
<info>list1</info>
<count>24</count>
<rtag>1111</rtag>
<rtag>2222</rtag>   ------upto 24 rtags
```

I want to display the contents as below

```
list1   1111 2222 3333 ----------upto 10 items{next line}
          1011 1022 1033-----------upto 10 times{next line}
          1001 1002 1003--till remaining items
```

here in this case I am getting count from the backend.I want to display the items as shown above dynamically using value of count by calling template.can anyone please help me in getting this?

Comment: So the output format should be plain text? Please create sample XML and sample output that actually *match* each other. Also: How many "lists" are there? How are they separated?

Comment: There will be 20 lists in a page and each list may contain n number of rtags.everything will be arranged in rows and coloumns.

Comment: @VinayHere, count tag holds the number of rtags?

Comment: @Vinay Seriously. There are three easy questions, I can't believe I must repeat them to you. **1)** Will the output be be plain text? **2)** How many lists of rtags are there? **3)** How are they separated in the XML? Can it be so difficult to answer these?

Comment: @Tomalak sorry for the inaccurate reply.Here you go 1)Output is each list(ex:list1) and each rtag itself will be a hyperlin(ex:2222 will be a hyperlink) 2) Max of 20 lists will be there(ex: list1, list2, list3...upto list20) and each list may contain 'n' number of rtags. 3)In XML they are seperated exactly how you have posted in you answer and ther will be 20 such lists. Hope I made it clear

Comment: @'Aravind' yes count tag holds number of rtags

Comment: @Vinay Now you have a solution that creates plain text because you did not mention that you want HTML. Please be more precise next time, because not being precise wastes everybody's time. :-(

Comment: @Tomalak Sure Will improve myself next time..This is my first question. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Windows-1252" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:variable name="padding1" select="'        '" /><!-- first col -->
  <xsl:variable name="padding2" select="'      '" />  <!-- remaining cols -->
  <xsl:variable name="per-row"  select="10" />        <!-- column count -->

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:value-of select="info" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($padding1, string-length(info) + 1)" /> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rtag" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rtag">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() mod $per-row = 1 and position() &gt; 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$padding1" />
        <xsl:call-template name="padded-value" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="padded-value" />
        <xsl:if test="position() mod $per-row = 0 or position = last()">
          <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="padded-value">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($padding2, string-length() + 1)" /> 
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to

```
<list>
  <info>list1</info>
  <count>24</count>
  <rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag>
  <rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag><rtag>1111</rtag>
  <rtag>222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag>
  <rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag><rtag>2222</rtag>
  <rtag>333</rtag><rtag>3333</rtag><rtag>3333</rtag><rtag>3333</rtag>
</list>
```

produces

```
list1     1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111  1111
           222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222  2222
           333  3333  3333  3333
```